# ROOT-installing with cmake succeds but is not usable

Tags: compiling, root, c++

I currently am working with Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. You should know that I am completly knew to any Linux environments, so please excuse my lack of details if there's any.

I have to work with the library ROOT for C++, developped by the CERN. Installation with `sudo make install` has failed, and I had to install it through `cmake`.

When I launch a terminal and type in `root`, it seems to work, displaying all informations correctly.

However, when using the following `makefile` (included at the end of the post), I get a really extended error report which starts with:

```
g++ -Wall -c -o Precision_DiffFinie.o -I`~/root-6.12.04/builddir/bin/root-config --incdir`  Precision_DiffFinie.cpp 
 In file included from /home/benjamin/root-6.12.04/builddir/include/RtypesCore.h:23:0,
             from /home/benjamin/root-6.12.04/builddir/include/Rtypes.h:23,
             from /home/benjamin/root-6.12.04/builddir/include/TObject.h:17,
             from /home/benjamin/root-6.12.04/builddir/include/TNamed.h:25,
             from /home/benjamin/root-6.12.04/builddir/include/TGraph.h:24,
             from Precision_DiffFinie.cpp:15:
/home/benjamin/root-6.12.04/builddir/include/RConfig.h:47:4: error: #error "ROOT requires support for C++11 or higher."
 #  error "ROOT requires support for C++11 or higher."
^
 /home/benjamin/root-6.12.04/builddir/include/RConfig.h:49:5: error:  #error "Pass `-std=c++11` as compiler argument."
 #error "Pass `-std=c++11` as compiler argument."
 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/atomic:38:0,
             from /home/benjamin/root-6.12.04/builddir/include/Rtypes.h:29,
             from /home/benjamin/root-6.12.04/builddir/include/TObject.h:17,
             from /home/benjamin/root-6.12.04/builddir/include/TNamed.h:25,
             from /home/benjamin/root-6.12.04/builddir/include/TGraph.h:24,
             from Precision_DiffFinie.cpp:15:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support \
```

I think the following errors are due to the C++ compiler not understanding what I wrote as it couldn't link to the ROOT library.

Does anyone know how to fix that, or might explain to me what I am doing wrong? I tried to do everything good, but I surely have missed something ; and I have been trying to fix this for too long to understand anythong on my own, now.

The`makefile` :

```
# Makefile pour les exercices de calculs numeriques

# definition du compilateur
GPP=g++ -Wall

# lien vers les fichiers d'en-tete des classes ROOT (ROOTINC) et les librairies (ROOTLIB), cad les fichiers binaires
ROOTINC=-I`root-config --incdir`
ROOTLIB=`root-config --libs`

#La liste des executables a compiler
# les executables sont en .exe pour pouvoir beneficier de la regle generique de conversion de .o en .exe
EXE=MinMaxTableau.exe Optimisation_CalculSerie.exe Precision_DiffFinie.exe MethodeSecante.exe

#######################################################################################

# la premiere instruction du makefile est celle par défaut - quand on tape make sans donner d'argument après

all: ${EXE} 

####################################################################################### 

# Compilation

# Des classes
%.o:%.cpp %.h
    ${GPP} -c -o $@ ${ROOTINC}  $<

# Des programmes principaux
%.o:%.cpp
    ${GPP} -c -o $@ ${ROOTINC}  $<  

#######################################################################################

# Edition des liens
# Regle de conversion de chaque .o en .exe
%.exe: %.o 
    ${GPP} -o $@ $^ ${ROOTLIB}

#######################################################################################

# nettoyage
clean:
    rm -rf *.o ${EXE} *.pdf *.root *.png Print
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Just curious why you do not want to use [pre-compiled from **"Binary distributions"** section](https://root.cern.ch/content/release-61204)?

Comment: @N0rbert I downloaded that, used `./configure`, then `make` and finally `sudo make install`, as I was instructed to at my college. I encountered issues at different points of this process, mainly at the `sudo` part. After a little digging, the website recommanded using `cmake` when such problems occured. Should I try it again with the old not-working method?

Comment: I have never used ROOT, but binary is usually simpler to use.

Comment: Based on [Building ROOT](https://root.cern.ch/building-root) it looks like the `cmake` configures the compiler with `cxx11 ON` by default, and it wants you to do the same for programs built and linked with it - so try adding `-std=c++11` to your `GPP` definition

Comment: @steeldriver Adding `-std=c++11` worked perfectly! I just do not know how to say it solved my problem. Can you tell me how or just post-it as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see that [ordinary `make` builds is not recommended by CERN](https://root.cern.ch/building-root), but you can try.

```
wget https://root.cern.ch/download/root_v6.12.04.source.tar.gz
tar -xzf root_v6.12.04.source.tar.gz

sudo apt-get install git dpkg-dev cmake g++ gcc binutils libx11-dev libxpm-dev \
libxft-dev libxext-dev

sudo apt-get install gfortran libssl-dev libpcre3-dev \
xlibmesa-glu-dev libglew1.5-dev libftgl-dev \
libmysqlclient-dev libfftw3-dev libcfitsio-dev \
graphviz-dev libavahi-compat-libdnssd-dev \
libldap2-dev python-dev libxml2-dev libkrb5-dev \
libgsl0-dev libqt4-dev

./configure
make -j4
sudo make install
```

Also for your information - Ubuntu Xenial has [ROOT 5.34 packages in repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/root-system-bin). You can install them with

```
sudo apt-get install root-system-bin
```